# Using Powershell to create a comma delimited text file from xml files located in different folders

Tags: xml, powershell

On a Windows 7 PC, I'm trying to generate a single comma-delimited text file from data contained in several hundred xml files.  Each xml file is contained in its own uniquely-named folder, but each instance of the xml file has the same file name, "report.xml"

To be more clear, the folder / file structure is something like this:

```
H:\Main_Folder\Folder_1\report.xml
H:\Main_Folder\Folder_2\report.xml
H:\Main_Folder\Folder_3\report.xml
...
```

The xml files contain lots of data, but I am only interested in a couple of data items, which happen to be measurements.  Ultimately, my desired output is a text file that would list, for every folder, the folder name and the two measurements from the xml file:

```
folder_1 , measurement_1 , measurement_2
folder_2 , measurement_1 , measurement_2
folder_3 , measurement_1 , measurement_2
...
```

Within any folder, I am able to get the values I want from a single xml file with the following PowerShell code:

```
$xml = [xml](get-content report.xml)
$xml.Measurement[0].Value.'#text' + " , " + $xml.Measurement[1].Value.'#text'
```

The above code returns:

```
measurement_1 , measurement_2
```

Also, I can move through each folder and output the folder name with the following PowerShell code:

```
PS H:\Main_Folder> Get-ChildItem Report.xml -Recurse | Split-Path -parent
```

When executed, this gives me:

```
folder_1
folder_2
folder_3
...
```

I need some help to figure out how to get all of this to work together to produce my desired text file. Many thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this

```
ls h:\main_folder -filter "report.xml" -recurse|%{
    [xml]$xml=gc $_.FullName
    $_.DirectoryName+","+$xml.Measurement[0].Value.'#text' + " , " + $xml.Measurement[1].Value.'#text' |out-file c:\temp\output.csv -Append
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, and I think we're on the right track.  However, `ls h:\main_folder -filter "report.xml"` doesn't return anything as there is another folder between the main_folder and the report.xml.

Comment: Again, thanks!  With the added -recurse, the first line of the expression is working.  However, now I get a series of error messages: `Cannot index into a null array.`

Comment: are you sure all your xml contains measurement tag ? please provide complete error msg

Comment: `Cannot index into a null array.`
`At line:3 char:5`
`+     $_.DirectoryName + "," + ... `
`+~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ `
`    + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException `
`    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray `

Comment: is it working for some of your files ? if so you must have differents structured xml

Comment: Out of the huge number of folders I'm processing, a small percentage did not contain a properly formatted report.xml.  These rare files were responsible for the error messages.  When I checked the output.csv file, >95% were done correctly.  So, your answer is awesome.  Thanks so much.